# Actionable Notification from Terminated State

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, apple-push-notifications

I have implemented actionable notifications in my app, and the 3 actions are appearing when you swipe down on the notification. Tapping on the actions works if the app is in the foreground or background state, but not when the app is in the terminated state. After some debugging, I discovered that when in the background or foreground state, the didReceiveNotificationResponse method is called (expected behavior), but from the terminated state, it calls didFinishLaunchingWithOptions and the launchOptions dictionary is nil. How can I get it to call didReceiveNotificationResponse from the terminated state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to  https://nrj.io/simple-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8/
You just need to implement the wanted dedicated methods:

```
application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forLocalNotification:completionHandler:
application:handleActionWithIdentifier:forRemoteNotification:completionHandler:
```

Comment: Because launch options is nil, so there is no metadata to process. I need to know which action the user selected in the notification. It may be a bug because it seems as though all the info is just lost.

Comment: Oh you mean you wanted to implement 
`- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler` ?

Comment: More info here https://nrj.io/simple-interactive-notifications-in-ios-8/
If yes i can integrate the answer

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thank you! Weird that they have two different delegate methods for background and terminated states.

Comment: Yes it's pretty confusing :)

Comment: I think the issue is that they completely changed the UserNotifications framework in iOS 10 and I was following the iOS 10 documentation. The tutorial you linked is for iOS 8 and it seems to have the correct answer, even for iOS 10.